# As far as reputation, why does accepting a crappy answer effectively cancel out a down vote on a question asked?

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions

Or am I wrong?  Just curious.  Any metric system is fascinating.

Comment: My downvote here is for two reasons 1) 90% of the content of your post is hidden in the title which in my view counts as "poorly asked" 2) Even after the edit you've still resorted to using crude language to make up for an apparent lack of articulation.

Comment: I'm lost here, what's the heart of this complaint?

Comment: "Hidden in the title"....  um, what?  It is a short and simple question, and NOT a complaint.  Please answer it if you can.

Answer (score 3):

Usually people downvote on a question when they feel that the question is not useful to the community or maybe it is not properly formatted or the OP has not put in effort to research basic steps before asking the question. That does not mean that the answer provided would be crappy or not significant. However, if community feels, that both question and answers will not help the community people in anyway then the question would rather get more downvotes and would also be closed. So in that end, it does not matter if one downvote on the question gets cancelled out by accepting an answer w.r.t reputation.

Answer (score 2):

A single downvote on a question really isn't enough to worry about. Yes, the reputation that you gain from accepting an answer *does* cancel the reputation lost from a downvote, but that isn't really significant. In my opinion, *the 2-rep incentive to accept answers outweighs any disadvantages associated with "cancelling" a downvote.*